# Не полное выделение памяти с++ malloc

Tags: c++, указатели, память, malloc

От чего у меня выделяется память только для одного элемента?

```
...
        double * dd = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof (double));
        std::cout << "multiple void dd " << sizeof (dd)/sizeof (double) << " size "<< size <<std::endl;
...
run

multiple void dd 1 size 2625
```

Вторая реализация с исправлением:

```
...
    double * dd = new double (size);
    free(dd);
    double dd1 = *dd;;
    std::cout << "multiple void dd1 " << sizeof (dd1)/sizeof (double) << " size "<< size <<std::endl;
...

run

multiple void dd1 1 size 2625
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас выделяется память для `size` элементов, которое, судя по выводу, у вас равно 2625.

Если же вас интересует, почему

```
sizeof (dd)/sizeof (double)
```

дает 1 - так это потому, что размер **указателя** (`dd`) в 64-разрадной программе равен 8 и совпадает с размером `double`. Была бы 32-разрядная программа - было бы значение 0...

Comment: Меня, в том числе, интересует определение размера массива через указатель.

Comment: @shaman888 Это невозможно. Размер придется хранить в отдельной переменной. А лучше - перестаньте использовать `new`/`delete` "вручную" и переходите на `std::vector`.

Comment: Ну... тогда надо вскрывать работу менеджера памяти и молиться, чтоб он не изменился к следующей версии компилятора (и, понятно, что для другого компилятора все нужно начинать сначала...)